# Can't add a class to links in the visual editor since WP 3.1?

Tags: links, tinymce

Did this feature chang in 3.1?
I recall that I could change the class of the link in the thickbox popup.

[image: Link dialog in WP 3.0.5]
[image: Link dialog in WP 3.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link window was [completely redesigned in 3.1](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11420) to make it easier to link to other posts in your blog. The "title" and "class" attributes were removed from this window, probably because the UI team thought they were not used as often?

Comment: yes, i've just figured out a batter way for my need also, so its probably for the best :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a shame they have canceled the ability to add classes to links.
Do you know a good workaround to add them?

I now use this one, but this will wrap the anchor with another p or span tags and it's really unnecessary ..

```
//add tinyMCE styles
function tc_add_formatTinyMCE($init) { 
    $init['theme_advanced_buttons2_add'] = 'styleselect';  
    $init['theme_advanced_styles'] = 'friendlyname=classname, friendlyname2=another-classname  ';  
    return $init;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tc_add_formatTinyMCE' );
```

Comment: i, personally think that it simpler that way. you can use the CSS class `#content a` and sibilings for a unified class for all of the content links. The problem is if U want to use several different anchor classes.

Comment: This is exactly the issue, for letting the user to have different anchor classes. For example, I have a site that the editor needs sometimes a very big button in s special location on page. I added that class to the tinyMCE, and editor knows that whenever he needs that button, he just add this button from the list, and then the class is being added for this one special link on the page. I am still looking for a good solution for this issue, if you have any I'll be happy to hear.. Thanks