# Add a class to links in the visual editor (how to get old dialog back)

Tags: php, javascript, links, tinymce, customization

New:

[image: This is new new Dialog]

Old:

[image: Old wordpress Add link dialog]

In short, i want a list of some classes **inside** the add link dialog. Because this was default there might be a easy way to get it back like this?

Long:
I like to have the ability to add classes to themes. I have found 2 plugins for that. One breaks tinymce and the other [add link class plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/insert-link-class/) produces a hell of a lot notices (with `WP_DEBUG` enabled) but it works it puts a select box to tiny mce and there i can change classes. But i don't like it that way. It created span's when there is no link marked. Back in the days it was just like I want it now. Also there are all sort of wordpress default classes in that dropdown box a also don't like.

[There is this question about it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12525/cant-add-a-class-to-links-in-the-visual-editor-since-wp-3-1), but no good answers there, the author stated that he found a better way to accomplish his goal but did not bother to share it with us.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the plugin [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/).

> Enables the advanced features of TinyMCE, the WordPress WYSIWYG editor.

In its configuration page (`Settings > TinyMCE Advanced`), you'll find this option:

[image: detail of tinymce configuration screen]

That option will convert the pop-up window of the "Insert/Edit Link" button into this:

[image: Insert/Edit Link tinymce popup window]

[image: Insert/Edit Link tinymce popup window - advanced tab]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working any more as of today.

Comment: Any contemporary solution to this? The latest version of WP as of today is 4.7.5.

Comment: The solution now can be found using the same plugin but slightly different steps. See this thread from the plugin author: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-add-classes-in-link-dialog/

Comment: The plugin isn't being actively maintained by the look of it.  In the spirit of WPSE, does anyone have a coded solution to this?